# Visual Studio WPF - QT Designer like grid layout

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, qt, qt-designer

Is there any way to layout grids in VS like in QT Designer? Like dragging and dropping in new elements, each automatically confined in its own cell, automatically alligned to the row / column the got dropped in etc.?

I see how I can achieve the same layouts like in QT in the end by manually specifing a bunch of column and row definitions, and additionally specifing by hand the positioning of each element in each cell, but it is like ten times the work it takes to layout the elements in QT designer and I cannot imagine VS being this bad in this aspect.

To give an example:
[image: QT Grid]
A grid like this, I can drag and drop together in QT in a matter of 2 minutes, with automatic adjusting column width, empty cells etc. In WPF, a uniform grid gets close to what I need, but it does not permit for empty cells (ok, I can place an empty label but thats kind of bad style), and the row widths are uniform, which does not work for me.

Comment: Use [Microsoft Blend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Blend).

Comment: I'm not familiar with QT, but have a look at the second part of [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/03/layout-techniques-for-windows-forms-developers.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) - does that help?

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is the right direction. It is still not as comfortable as in QT (still have to click each column and row seperately to get them to auto-adjust), but at least I don't have to fix widths and heigths manually.

Answer (score 0):

Write XAML directly, or if you must then use Blend.

The VS designer has always been garbage, i for one do not use any graphical designer; there simply is no need for that if you have clean markup like XAML and don't need to write some spaghetti code that imperatively creates the view.

Comment: I prefer a mixed approach, first creating a rough layout with a visual designer and then finetuning the code (with QT, the .ui file, and now in C# the .xaml). I think it saves me a lot of time, as long as the visual editor is decent (like QT Designer).

Comment: @user3696412: For that to save time the designer really has to be good. In the past the VS designer created work by inserting Margins everywhere if one was not careful.